# LINQ search in list with space separated values

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for LINQ expression in C# to search space seperated sentence in a list of objects.

I have a list of places with these items.

```
var places=new List<Places>();
var place1=new Place(){Name="facebook twitter", OtherName="fun time"}
places.Add(place1);

var place2=new Place(){Name="facebook microsoft", OtherName="fun programming"}
places.Add(place2);

var place3=new Place(){Name="Microsoft CMS", OtherName="fun CMS"}
places.Add(place3);
```

search query = "facebook time" or "time facebook"
Expected result = place1

search query = "microsoft fun" or "fun microsoft"
Expected result = place2 and place3

search query = "fun micro program" or "micro fun program"
Expected result = place2

I have tried this code but it does not return any result f search query has words seperated by a space.

```
var queryParts = query.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var filteredList = places.Where(x => queryParts.Any(y => x.Name.Contains(y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) || queryParts.Any(y => x.OtherName.Contains(y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
```

Note: contains is an extension method

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work if search query is a sentence*? And how should work if the query is a sentence?

Comment: It does not return result if search words are seperated by a space.

Comment: From your samples, I would expect a `&&` in the query, not `||`. Can you spell out the expected results more explicit?

Comment: Couldn't you combine the any call like `queryParts.Any(y => x.Name.Contains(y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || x.OtherName.Contains(y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: I have tried with both || and && but if query contains a space it does not return result

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) over the tokens contained in the search string. This query tries to match **all** of the given search words.

```
var queryParts = query.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var filteredList = 
    queryParts.Aggregate(places, (current, token) =>
        current.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(token, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
                        || p.OtherName.Contains(token, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
);
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zeFApd)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I'm assuming you want to return items in the list which contains **ALL** the words in your query. If that's the case, you just need to change your `Where()` like this:

```
var filteredList = places.Where(
    p => queryParts.All(
        q => p.Name.Contains(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
             || p.OtherName.Contains(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```